# Resultados de un select que no esten en otro select SQL

Tags: sql

estoy trabado en una consulta.
Tengo dos tablas, una llamada socio(idsocio, nombre, apellido) y una llamada alquiler(fechadevolucion)

La cuestión es que necesito obtener los socios que desde x tiempo no realizar un alquiler lo logro con esto:

```
SELECT s."idSocio", s."nombre", s."apellido"
FROM socio s, alquiler alq
WHERE alq."idSocio" = s."idSocio" AND NOT(alq."fechaDevolucion" > '01-01-2020')
```

Esto me trae todos los registros de los socios que no tengan un alquiler desde '01-01-2020'.

PEEERO, si un socio que tuvo un alquiler anterior a '01-01-2020' llegase a tener un alquiler en un fecha superior a '01-01-2020', la consulta no lo ve.

Estuve probando con esto pero la verdad que no funciona

```
SELECT s."idSocio", s."nombre", s."apellido"
FROM socio s, alquiler alq
WHERE alq."idSocio" = s."idSocio" AND NOT(alq."fechaDevolucion" > '01-01-2020')

AND NOT EXISTS IN(SELECT  s."idSocio", s."nombre", s."apellido"
FROM socio s, alquiler alq
WHERE alq."idSocio" = s."idSocio" AND NOT(alq."fechaDevolucion" < '01-01-2020'))
```

Si alguien con mejores conocimientos me puede guiar agradecería.

Comment: Por las dudas si alguien necesita aqui esta la solucion https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333413/consulta-sql-fechas-que-un-id-no-coincida/333446#333446

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Consulta sql fechas que un id no coincida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333413/consulta-sql-fechas-que-un-id-no-coincida)

Answer (score 0):

La consulta no trae los datos, porque con el not lo que estás diciendo es que no te traiga resultados donde "fechaDevolucion" sea mayor a 01-01-2020, y es por esto que una fecha superior no estará en los resultados.

Si mal no entiendo tu problema, deberías cambiar la consulta a:

```
SELECT s."idSocio", s."nombre", s."apellido" FROM socio s, alquiler alq WHERE alq."idSocio" = s."idSocio" AND (alq."fechaDevolucion" < '01-01-2020')
```

Con esto deberías traer todos los datos donde alq.idSocio = s.idSocio y alq.fechaDevolucion < 01-01-2020.

PD: Revisá las estructuras de las tablas, ya que esto deberías hacerlo con joins.

Comment: Pude solucionarlo, aqui lo explico https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333413/consulta-sql-fechas-que-un-id-no-coincida/333446#333446

Answer (score 0):

Pues considero que tú consulta debería ser así

```
SELECT socio.nombre, socio.apellido
FROM socio
LEFT JOIN alquiler ON socio.id = alquiler.socio_id
WHERE (alquiler.fechaDevolucion <= fechaaquí
OR alquiler.fechaDevolucion > fechaaqui);
```

De manera que

- Obtienes los datos de las dos tablas relacionadas por medio de join, en este caso un LEFT para que traiga tanto a socios que no han hecho alquiler pero también a esos que si lo hicieron después de la fecha indicada
- En el WHERE establecemos dos condiciones, la primera es para
- ESTABLECEMOS EL uso del operador OR para que cualquiera de las condiciones se cumpla y me regresé registros anteriores cuando no tiene alquiler y los posteriores donde si tiene

Comment: Pude solucionarlo, aqui lo explico https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333413/consulta-sql-fechas-que-un-id-no-coincida/333446#333446