# Consulta sql fechas que un id no coincida

Tags: sql

Tengo que Realizar una consulta que me devuelva los socios que no registren alquileres este año por ejemplo, si ven la imangen el socio numero 2 tiene alquileres del año pasado pero tambien tiene de este año por ende no lo quiero en los resultados, en cambio el socio numero 3 no registra alquileres este año 2020 ese resultado si me serviria.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto tambien la tabla socio por si alguien me ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado, qué has intentado, qué resultados/errores tienes en base a eso?

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final era mucho mas fácil de lo que imagine, desconozco si son buenas practicas, pero funciona a la perfección.
Dejo el resultado por si alguien la precisa.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s."idSocio", s."nombre", s."apellido", s."telefono", s."fechaAlta"
FROM socio AS s, alquiler AS al
WHERE s."idSocio" = al."idSocio" AND al."fechaDevolucion" < '01-01-2020'

EXCEPT

SELECT DISTINCT s."idSocio", s."nombre", s."apellido", s."telefono", s."fechaAlta"
FROM socio AS s, alquiler AS al
WHERE s."idSocio" = al."idSocio" AND al."fechaDevolucion" >= '01-01-2020'
```

Lo que hice fue un except entre dos select de esta forma si un socio realizo un alquiler antes de esa fecha, y tambien luego de esa fecha no es devuelto por la consulta, solo devuelve los anteriores a la fecha dada.

Comment: La consulta como texto por favor, además si esto es la solución no olvides explicarla y marcarla como aceptada

Comment: Gracias por las criticas, arreglado

Answer (score 1):

Ya está más que respondido, pero creo que si la idea es obtener socios y no registros de arriendo, el distinct es medio violento.

Yo haría algo como (simplificación, estoy en el teléfono)

```
SELECT s."idSocio", 
s."nombre", 
s."apellido", 
s."telefono", 
s."fechaAlta" 
FROM socio AS s
LEFT JOIN alquiler AS al 
ON s."idSocio" = al."idSocio" AND al."fechaDevolucion" < '01-01-2020' 
WHERE al.idSocio IS NULL
```

Un left join donde la parte derecha sea nula es por definición lo que está en la tabla izquierda y no en la derecha.

En el LEFT join puedes meter la condición de fecha y no filtrar en el WHERE

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a probar y comento si da con el caso